# EWS comparing ItemIDs shows no match but ItemID.ToString comparison shows a match.

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS to find items.  I expect the result set to be larger than the page size so I have implemented a check to ensure my result set doesn't change while paging.  The code is pretty much the same as recommended by Microsoft at the link below.

[How to: Perform paged searches by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn592093(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
if (results.Items.First<Item>().Id != anchorId)
{
    Console.Writeline("The collection has changed while paging. " + 
    "Some results may be missed.");
}
```

The problem is, the first ItemID and the acnchorID never match even though I am sure the collection is not changing.  Further to this, if I convert the IDs to strings and do a string comparison as below, they always match.

```
string a = results.Items.First<Item>().Id.ToString();
string b = anchorId.ToString();

bool result = a.Equals(b, StringComparison.Ordinal);

Debug.Print("Ordinal comparison: {0}",result ? "equal." : "not equal.");
```

I have tried running the code on different result sets and with different page sizes and the outcome is always the same: the ItemIds never match but the ID strings always match.

**Question**

I am reluctant to drop the approach recommended by Microsoft in favor of a string comparison approach especially as I can't explain why the FolderID comparison approach isn't working.  But, on the other hand, I can't explain why the string comparison always works.  Does anyone have any thoughts on why I might be seeing these strange and conflicting results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i sucpect is happening in this line:

```
if (results.Items.First<Item>().Id != anchorId)
```

Seeing that the ItemId object, or its parents, do not override the != operator. The object references of the ItemId are being compared. And this should always return true because we create a different object for each ItemId.

But the toString() method is being overriden by this  :

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return (this.uniqueId == null) ? string.Empty : this.uniqueId;
        }
```

Which explains why comparing this results in a good comparison of the keys. 
The best way to handle this i think is to use the equals method of the ItemId class which has its own implementation:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                ServiceId other = obj as ServiceId;

                if (other == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (!(this.IsValid && other.IsValid))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return this.UniqueId.Equals(other.UniqueId);
                }
            }
}
```

So conclusion use this for the comparison of the keys:

```
if (!results.Items.First<Item>().Id.Equals(anchorId))
{
    Console.Writeline("The collection has changed while paging. " + 
    "Some results may be missed.");
}
```

And if u are interested u can visit the github page for the source code: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api